# Can we say ''the Lagrange general solution of a quasi-linear PDE completely exhausts all the solutions except possibly the envelops''

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have solved the linear first order PDE:

$$u_x-u_y=0,~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(*)$$ using the Lagrange's method to get the general solution, $$F(x+y,u)=0,~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(a)$$where $F$ is arbitrary. Moreover, I found that $u=f(x+y)$ can form a general subclass of solutions.

Can we say that the general solution $(a)$ completely explored the solutions of $(*)$ except possibly the envelops (tangent to the solutions $(a)$)?

Or,

Can I say,

''for any function $h$, $u=h(.)$ is a solution for $(*)$ if and only if $h(.)=h(x+y)$''?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What do you mean by 'completely exhausts the solutions' and what are 'the envelops'? Note that the solution you gave $u = \color{red}{x + y} + f(x + y)$ can be written as $u = g(x + y)$ i.e the $\color{red}{x + y}$ term is redundant.

Comment: @MatthewCassell thanks for your corrections, and I hope bit more clear now.